# Django {{data|escapejs}} from a js static file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I use {{data|escapejs}} django banner to import some data in my the javascript of my page.
Simple example :

```
<script>
console.log({{data|escapejs}})
</script>
```

But it doesn't work if I place this line in a .js static file

```
<script src = "{% static 'mycode.js' %}>
```

In mycode.js :

```
console.log({{data|escapejs}})
```

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Okeeyy ... finally, it was easy.

```
<script>
var myvar = {{data|escapejs}}
</script>
<script src = "{% static 'mycode.js' %}">
```